# Some problems encountered when using deconvolution

Tags: mxnet, deconvolution

the version of mxnet is 0.9, I use the Deconvolution operator base on resnet-50 for instance segmentation, but after dealing with several batch， the program breaks down, the error message is

```
[17:36:55] /home/gnss/mxnet/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/./logging.h:300: [17:36:55] src/operator/./cudnn_deconvolution-inl.h:205: Check failed: req[deconv::kBias] != kWriteInplace (2 vs. 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to upgrade to `1.2.0` as there might be some problems in the old versions.

Also, if you just want to have a ResNet model up and running, take a look to [gluon-cv model zoo](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/api/model_zoo.html). There are some pretrained models for semantic segmentation available out of the box.